# fortnightly C# logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Anyone please help me with fortnightly C# MVC 5 calendar logic. I've implemented weekly dates.

This is my weekly code. It is working.

```
var day = (from o in db.Suburbs.AsEnumerable()
    ..etc
    select new 
    {

    DT.DeliveryDay,
}).ToList();


foreach (var temp in day)
{
    if (Type == "weekly")
    {
        int weeklyLogic = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
        DateTime  nextweeklyLogic = today.AddDays(weeklyLogic);
        Firstweek = nextweeklyLogic;
        int weekly2 = (((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7) + 7;
        DateTime Secondweek = today.AddDays(weekly2);
        int weekly3 = (((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7) + 14;
        DateTime Thirdweek = today.AddDays(weekly3);
        etc..
    }
    else if (Type == "fortnightly")
    {

    }
}
```

For example, with `Type == "fortnightly"`, say for example `temp.DeliveryDay == "Friday"`, then based on today (February 2nd), I would expect the output to be:

```
February 5th (First Friday after today, since temp.DeliveryDay is friday)
February 19th (14 days or fortnight from the first output)
March 4th
etc.
```

Comment: That edit didn't help. Can you explain what exactly you mean by fortnightly? Do you mean two-week periods starting from a certain Monday? Or another day? You can test for say first Monday (or other day of week) in a month fairly simply (`day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && day.Day <= 7`), but it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do as it is. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have updated my question. my else loop how do I display fortnightly date

Comment: Hello @jdphenix, Are u clear my question? for example this month start from fortnightly(14 days). Monday 8th February (Next day 15, 29, etc..) or Monday 8th February (Next day 15, 29, etc..)

Comment: Well, you're parsing the DayOfWeek from a string, so say you're passed in "Friday" and today is... today - your expected output for fortnight would be Feb 5, Feb 19, Mar 4, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - you're repeating all of your behavior to get the weekly dates. I'd recommend decomposing the operation you have. I see two main parts.

- Get the date of the first arbitrary day of week after today.
- Get a periodic recurring date from the date determined above.

This method can take care of the first part,

```
DateTime FirstDayOfWeekAfter(DateTime day, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    // We don't want to return today. 
    day = day.AddDays(1);

    // If the current tested day is the desired day of week, return. 
    if (day.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
    {
        return day;
    }
    // else call again with the next day.
    else
    {
        return FirstDayOfWeekAfter(day, dayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

And this pair of methods would take care of the second part. I have the first method here just so casting to (DayOfWeek) isn't necessary when you actually use it.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(DateTime today, object dayOfDelivery, int period)
{
    return GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(today, (DayOfWeek)dayOfDelivery, period);
}

IEnumerable<DateTime> GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(DateTime today, DayOfWeek dayOfDelivery, int period)
{
    // Get the date of the first delivery. 
    var firstDelivery = FirstDayOfWeekAfter(today, dayOfDelivery);

    while (true)
    {
        // Infinitely yield dates separated by the supplied period length.
        yield return firstDelivery;
        firstDelivery = firstDelivery.AddDays(period);
    }
}
```

Usage of these methods is straightforward. The only difference between the weekly and fortnightly enumerables is that period passed in to `GetPeriodicDeliveryDates()`. You do want to make sure not to attempt to fully enumerate over `GetPeriodicDeliveryDates()` - it's in infinite sequence.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var temp = new { DeliveryDay = "Friday" };

var weekly = GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(today, Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay), 7);
var fortnightly = GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(today, Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay), 14);

weekly.Take(5).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
Console.WriteLine();
fortnightly.Take(5).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Thank you for advice and C# code
There was
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DeliveryDates(System.DateTime, object, int)'
code line  var weekly = GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(today, Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay), 7);

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to access an instance member of a class from a static context - in your shoes I'd recommend picking up a C# programming book and running through it - Head First C# is a good resource, and there's some other good ones out there as well

Comment: I have changed to this line var weekly = (GetPeriodicDeliveryDates(today,((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), temp.DeliveryDay)),7));, but still same (An object reference is required for the non-static field , method, or property object, int)

Comment: Hello jdphenix, In your while loop, when  add date Tuesday date will populated 16th, 23rd, 30th etc... It is not populated 9th, What do I have to modify your while loop?

Comment: @Rob The code in the answer has a bug in it. If you look at the `FirstDayOfWeekAfter()`, it increments the day twice. Oops. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for fixed issue. I have question same method, for example I want display before 12pm today same date (5th, 12th, 19, 26 etc.. after 12pm 12th, 19th, 26 etc..) I added below code DateTime breaks = DateTime.Today.AddHours(12D);
if (breaks >= DateTime.Now)
            {
                day = day;
            }
            else
            {
                day = day.AddDays(1);
            }  but top loop did not work it always same date, loop infinitive

Comment: I'd recommend walking through your expected results with a pencil and paper or a whiteboard, and see what you can come up with. If, after doing that, you need help, I'd recommend posting a new question with your code that you've tried so far, the input/expected output, and a concise, clear explanation of the problem.